# Disabling opcache.enable in php.ini not working on CentOS

Tags: php, centos7, opcache

I have a CentOS 7 machine with PHP 5.6 installed on it via Webtatic's [`php56w` repo](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/). I installed the opcache extension with `yum install php56w-opcache`.

Since this is a development machine, I want to turn opcache off by default, so in my `/etc/php.ini` file, I put the following line:

```
opcache.enable = 0
```

However, after restarting my webserver, I can see in `phpinfo()` the `opcache.enable` is still On.

Did I miss something? How can I turn the opcache off?

Comment: Did you update the correct php.ini file? Most installations have at least two, one for web and a second for command line

Answer (score 4):

Installing `php56w-opcache` creates a file named /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini. This file contains the option `opcache.enable=1` by default, and will override your settings in `php.ini`.

I edited that file and changed `opcache.enable=1` to `opcache.enable=0` then restarted Apache and now opcache is disabled.